# Bash: Any way to print a variable inside a string surrounded by single quotes?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a variable $NEWFILE which i want to print inside of a string surrounded by single quotes like this

`cp '/path/to/file/$NEWFILE' /path/to/another/file`

$NEWFILE can be variable like `sunny fields.jpg`. Basically I want the final output to be

`cp '/path/to/file/sunny fields.jpg' /path/to/another/file`

How do I go about this?
I tried to put the whole string inside double quotes

`cp "'/path/to/file/$NEWFILE'" /path/to/another/file`

for $NEWFILE = 'sunny fields.jpg'. But it didn't work as expected

Comment: How are you printing, using `echo` using `printf`, etc. ? The `$variable` inside the double quotes is evaluated.

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Also, are you just trying to print the command, or to actually execute it? Because if you add quotes in such a way that they'll print, they will *not* be executed properly.

Comment: Please refer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209972/235648

Comment: Your ques ion is unclear to me: Do you want to **generate** a suitable `cp` command in the bash syntax, or do you actually want to **copy** files (i.e. execute a `cp`). Describe the overall effect you want to achieve. I feel that you have here a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: `echo "cp '/path/to/file/$NEWFILE' /path/to/another/file"` should do what you ask. Does it not?

Comment: You don't need the single quotes around /path/to/file/$NEWFILE but use double quote marks around the two paths.

Answer (score 0):

single quotes don't allow, by default, expand variables (feature that you need), so if you just replace it's supposed to works (it worked in my test):

```
cp "/path/to/file/$NEWFILE" /path/to/another/file
```

I just removed your single quotes.